# No me lee los \n o /r o algunos de esos en python Que hago?

Tags: python

El la consola los caracteres de \n, \t, /r.. en vez de interpretarse como salto delinea o como sea se leen literalmente como literalmente "\n" por ejemplo que hago???? Aqui dejo el codigo...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket
import os

host = socket.gethostname()                                             #Nos da la IP de la maquina
port = 8056                                                             #Puerto del server
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096                                                      #Es el tamaño del que vamos a recibir los paquetes de informacion

socketS = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)             #Crea el server con protocolo TCP

socketS.bind((host, port))                                              #Vinculamos el server con un puerto y host
print("[INFO] Esperando conexion...") 
socketS.listen(5)                                                       #Esperamos la conexion del cliente...
conn, addr = socketS.accept()                                           #Establecemos conexion con el cliente
with conn:          
    print("[INFO] Conexion establecida")
    while True:
        print("----------------------------------")
        print("----------------------------------")
        dataEnv = input("Comando que quieres poner: ")
        print("----------------------------------")
        print("----------------------------------")
        if dataEnv != "" or dataEnv != " ":
            conn.send(dataEnv.encode('utf-8'))
        try:
            data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)                               #Recibimos datos del cliente
            dataDecode = data.decode('utf-8')                           #Decodificamos los datos recibimos    
                                                                        #Comprobamos si hemos recibido datos
            if data:
                print(repr("Resultado: /n {}".format(dataDecode)))      #Mostramos lo recibido
        except:
            input("[ERROR] El cliente no esta conectado")
            break
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se debe a que para que interprete las [secuencias de escape](https://123programando.wordpress.com/tag/secuencias-de-escape/), todos deben de estar con la denominada barra invertida o backslash (`\`), ya que si se pone con la barra normal (`/`) lo toma como un carácter que se debe de imprimir:

```py
print("Salto de  \n línea con barra invertida") 
print("Salto de  /n línea con barra normal")
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu caso en la siguiente línea es donde veo que utilizas este tipo de caracter:

```py
print(repr("Resultado: /n {}".format(dataDecode)))
```

En cual sale con la barra normal, y debería de ser con barra invertida tal que así:

```py
print(repr("Resultado: \n {}".format(dataDecode)))
```

Además `repr` también estaría ayudando a que la línea no se visualice correctamente, para ello es necesario eliminar `repr` también.
Ya que `repr` es una función que devuelve una cadena en su formato imprimible, es decir, **no resuelve las secuencias de escape**.

El siguiente código que también puedes visualizar en el [siguiente enlace](https://ideone.com/LhOpLr), gentileza del usuario [insolor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/143346/insolor) muestra como `repr` afecta.

```py
dataDecode = 111

print(repr("Resultado: \n {}".format(dataDecode)))
print("Resultado: \n {}".format(dataDecode))
```

**Resultado**

```
'Resultado: \n 111'
Resultado: 
 111
```

El código resultante en tu caso debería ser, sin `repr` y con barra invertida (`\`):

```py
print("Resultado: \n {}".format(dataDecode))
```

Comment: También es necesario eliminar repr

Comment: @insolor tienes razón, estaba buscando información para añadirla a la respuesta con respecto a eso :)

Comment: Gracias una cosa mas... este programa devuelve algo ques e trendria que imprimir por consola pero en vez de impromirlo con saltos de linea y todo bien imprime con \n o \r... Que hago?
Te dejo un fragmento de como me o devuelve:
12:59    <DIR>          0409\r\n27/12/2019